# angularjs bootstrap ui active tabs not loaded by default

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-bootstrap

i am using angularjs v1.5.5 and ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2. 
i loading page the dynamic. i have 3 pages. i want to load last page by default

```
  $scope.tabs = [
{ title:'Page A', template: 'a.html',  content:'' , loaded : false},
{ title:'Page B', template: 'b.html',  content:'', loaded : false },
{ title:'Page C', template: 'c.html', content:'', loaded : false, active : true }
```

];

[My Sample Code Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jL6gfw7xnLdvTSLsuFqF?p=preview)

Comment: It wil be more convenient if you provide code demo using SO code snippet feature instead of providing external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fairly simple.

By default the active tab is set to the first index in the tabset.
The active attribute on the `uib-tabset` was changed to the required tab number.

```
<uib-tabset active="3">
```

Here is the modified [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nNgxLAZgTXgOGYHMXxjU?p=preview)

**Source and Additional Read**

If you want to read more about the attributes and properties of Angular UI tabs, here is a link to the [documentation for tabs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)

Comment: It wil be more convenient if you provide code demo using SO code snippet feature instead of providing external link

Comment: @niyasc, it definitely is more convenient!However, the author had multiple pages in the demo, and considering it was already made, I edited the same.